# How can I automate the selection of an AirPlay device as the speaker for a Mac?

Tags: macos, airplay, shortcuts-app

On iOS there's Siri Shortcut action called "Change Playback Destination". This action doesn't work on Mac:

> **Note**
> When attempting to add a device that does not support groups, all other devices are remove as playback destinations first.
>
> This action can not be run on Mac.

Does anyone know of a way in which I can automate the selection of my HomePod as the speaker for my Mac, without having to resort to a Keyboard Maestro clicking macro or similar?

It can be a Terminal command, an app or a shortcut action, as long as I don't have to do it manually.

Comment: Please don't use images for text. For more information, please see [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged).

Comment: My bad. Thanks for correcting